# How to get the Reply Emails ? Need a Mail Server?

Tags: php, email, mail-server

As i'm knowing just about PHP and don't know at all about Mail Servers, what i want to know here is:

- How can i **get the "Replied" emails (from the receivers)** for the mails i've send (by using PHP, with a address like xxxxxxx@gmail.com)
- Does it need to setup my own Mail Server?
- Unless using own Mail Server, is there any other easy way?

  Honestly i'm not well understanding over IMAP or Email Protocols. Doing setup my own IMAP Server is far worse. Can it be done simply with a Web Hosting which supporting IMAP protocol? Or do i need to setup manually out from the start?

  To be brief, i need a simple guide.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a mail server if you don't already have a place where those reply-tos end up. Which adress are you sending them as? Where would you fetch the emails for those adress? You can ask PHP to log into any mail server that you'd fetch your emails from manually as well, so there shouldn't be a problem. But maybe I'm not getting you right.

Comment: Using the sending address like xxxx@gmail.com How can it be implemented ?

Comment: you need to speak IMAP to the server (what your client does when you fetch mails manually, except gmail of course typically is queried via web, but it still supports IMAP and I think even POP, an alternative protocol). see here http://php.net/manual/de/book.imap.php

Comment: Honestly i'm not well understanding over IMAP or Email Protocols. Doing setup my own IMAP Server is far worse. Can it be done simply with the Web Hosting (like Arvixe) which supporting IMAP protocol? Or do i need to setup manually out from the start?

Comment: IMAP would be needed to properly send mail as the gmail address, not receive it.

Comment: No need to set up your own server. GMail is the server. IMAP is the language your program needs to speak with the GMail server in order to retrieve emails. You don't need to bother with it; you just have to know it's IMAP you're looking for, and use the PHP wrappers which take care of that for you. MrGlass: IMAP can be used for receiving emails. POP could be also used for receiving emails, but has to be manually enabled in GMail afaik. So I do think IMAP is a sensible recommendation.

Comment: @Nicolas78 Can i simply follow the guides like (http://www.ralphworlddesign.com/blog/?p=80) ? Is it the correct way pls?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the reply address to an email you own. For the example you gave to work, you would need to have the xxxx@gmail.com account.

Most people use something along the lines of mailer@youdomain.com, ans then create an account for that on their ma8lserver.

If you want to use your own domain, you don't need to run your own mailserver. Gmail, hotmail, and others have services that let you use their mailservers for your fomain, for free.